# How to reset font-style in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

```
> window.CKEDITOR.version
< "3.6.4"
```

I use CKEditor with `"toolbar":"Full"`. How can I reset the choosen font-style oder size to a "default value", in sense of no explicit value set?

For example, I select "Comic Sans MS" but than I want to reset this. There's no option in CKEditor except the HTML editor. Is this right? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the text you want to un-style and then reclick on the choosen font / style / whatever. CKEditor will remove this style.

Comment: I have a similar concern where I need to prevent resetting the font if we select it again.
Describing problem here: If you select a text in CKEditor and set its font say 14, it applies that font. Now select same text again and select same font (as selected earlier), your text will be reset to same font as it was having in original.

I want to stop this because it causes problem when I have some existing text and I paste additional paragraphs into it, now selecting one font and style for all text only works second time, because for the first instance it just resets the previous text to default.